# How do you create a list of repeated tuples in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Say I have a list of tuples, I extract the first tuple from this list and then want to create a new list that simply takes the first tuple and repeats it n times creating a list of tuples? Thanks.

Comment: What do the tuples contain? Show your input and expected output.

Answer (score 4):

Since tuples are immutable you may be able to do:

```
lst = [tuples[0]]
repeated = lst * 10 # create a list of the first tuple repeated 10 times
```

If they contain mutable objects changes in any of them will reflect in all of them, since these are the same objects repeated.

Comment: tuple multiplication will return a single tuple with the items repeated, not multiple tuples

Comment: @RNar He's multiplying the **list of tuples**, so it will return a list filled with 10 same tuples.

Comment: weird, I swear those brackets weren't there before haha

Comment: @RNar It was the brackets that I missed too, I had gotten a single tuple with the items repeated.

Comment: Thanks @Reut Sharabani. Works now.

Comment: @ReutSharabani you sly dog

Answer (score 2):

Let say that you have a list like this one:

```
list_of_tuples = [('foo', 'bar'), ('baz', 'qux')]
```

If you want to repeat the first tuple n times, you can use `itertools.repeat`

```
import itertools
itertools.repeat(list_of_tuples[0], n)
```

where `n` is the number of times you want the first tuple to be repeated.
`itertools.repeat` will return a generator.